# Cant find kendo aspnetmvc zip file download

Tags: kendo-ui

This may be a bit of a silly question, but here goes..

I'm new to kendo UI and asp.net mvc, so i got myself a book to get me started.
However, in the exercise in the book, they use a kendo for asp.net mvc zip file.
I have looked around on the kendoUI website and it also says that you have the option to either download the msi or a zip file, but for the asp.net download, it does not give me an option, just automatically downloads the msi installer.

Anybody know how I can get the kendo UI Complete for asp.net MVC??

Will really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: might not answer your question exactly but i think this - http://bizvise.com/2012/11/28/how-to-create-kendoui-asp-mvc-4-project/ will get you started with KendoUI ASP MVC wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the different packages and download them here: http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx

They have a 30 day trial for "Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC"

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction) is a good introduction to ASP.NET MVC and there is a [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/65b78c2c-951e-43a8-bae7-f9039f59fb9b) to where to find all you need.

Check also their page on ASP.NET MVC [here](http://www.kendoui.com/server-wrappers/mvc.aspx) where you can also find a link to the downloads.